# How to retain image data of type varbinary at edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, binary-data, entity-framework-5, razor-2

I have a small demo application to work around Binary data stored in the database. See below for related code:

**Entity Class:**

```
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Display(Name = "Photo:")]
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
```

**Edit Action:**

```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
         var mensPlayer = _dataSource.MensPlayers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        return View(mensPlayer);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MensPlayer mensPlayer, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //Added line below
            _dataSource.ImageTemp(mensPlayerInDb, mensPlayer);
            if (image != null)
            {
                mensPlayer.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                mensPlayer.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(mensPlayer.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
            }
              //Added line below
             mensPlayer.ImageData = mensPlayerInDb.ImageData;

            //Save Player
            _dataSource.Update(mensPlayer);
           _dataSource.Save();
          TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", mensPlayer.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "MensPlayer", new {id = mensPlayer.Id});
        }
        return View(mensPlayer);
    }
```

**GetImage Method:**

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int id)
    {
        var image = _dataSource.MensPlayers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (image != null)
        {
            return File(image.ImageData, image.ImageMimeType);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Display Image:

```
@if (Model.ImageData != null) {
    <div >
         <img width="300" height="400" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "MensPlayer",
                                        new { Model.Id })" alt="Player Image"/>
     </div>
 }
```

**DataSource class**

```
public interface IDataSource
{
    IQueryable<MensTeam> MensTeams { get; }
    IQueryable<MensPlayer> MensPlayers { get; }
    IQueryable<MensHome> MensHomes { get; }
    void Save();
    void Update(MensPlayer mensPlayer);
    void Delete();
    void ImageTemp(MensPlayer mensPlayerInDb, MensPlayer mensPlayer);//I added this
}
```

**In Db class**

```
void IDataSource.Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }

    void IDataSource.Update(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        Entry(mensPlayer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
     //Added code below
    void IDataSource.ImageTemp(MensPlayer mensPlayerInDb, MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        Entry(mensPlayerInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(mensPlayer);
    }
```

My problem is, every time i try to edit a player, every data is nicely retrieved from the database but when i hit save after editing, the ImageData is lost, more like replacing the original data with null value. It's like, the application expects me to re-upload the image at every edit i attempt.

What can i do to clean this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if `image` is `null` then in your entity `mensPlayer.ImageData` is `null`. Later when you call `_dataSource.Update(mensPlayer)` you set the state of the entity to `Modified` (at least I guess that `Update` just sets the state to `Modified`), so you are telling EF that your have modified the image too (namely set it to `null`) and EF will save that change.

In order to solve the problem you can either load the entity including the image from the database first...

```
var mensPlayerInDb = context.MensPlayers.Find(mensPlayer.Id);
mensPlayer.ImageData = mensPlayerInDb.ImageData; // save the ImageData
// copy changed values to loaded entity and save it, ImageData is unchanged
context.Entry(mensPlayerInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(mensPlayer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

...or you can try:

```
context.Entry(mensPlayer).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(mensPlayer).Property(m => m.ImageData).IsModified = false;
```

The latter approach didn't work with EF < 5.0 (because it was forbidden to set the `Modified` state of a property to `false` once the entity was marked as `Modified`) but it should work with EF 5.

You need to integrate one of the solutions into your `_dataSource` service class, possibly by introducing new methods because it won't work with your general `Update` method.

Comment: Sorry, i was stack with some stuff in life but i am back again. The 2nd option looked easy to implement but spits out an error as the first line sets everything to modified. In the 1st option, i understand what what the code is archiving but i have had trouble implementing the solution. See about and advise if i am in the right track.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: But you don't use `ImageTemp` anywhere and you don't load the original image from the database, do you?

Comment: I have updated the Edit Action. But one question.Is this line neccessay:`var mensPlayerInDb = context.MensPlayers.Find(mensPlayer.Id);` when i have this line: `var model = _dataSource.MensPlayers.Single(p => p.Id == id);` in my HttpGet? I have trouble understaning Find property used in that line of code? Comes up red in my source code when i build

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: You can use `Single` as well. You don't have `Find` because in your _dataSource `MensPlayer` is an `IQueryabl<T>` and not a `DbSet<T>`.